# FFMPEG, colormatrix and WEBM conversion

Tags: ffmpeg

I met this anon on 4chan who made me notice a color issue in my webms. I generally make webm using ffmpeg and I never noticed a change in colors. He suggested me to change the color matrix into 601 but I have no idea of the criteria he used in the first place.

[image]

Why there is this difference in colors from source (mkv) and output (webm)? What's the best way to preserve the color scheme during conversion/compression? This is the typical command I use when I convert from mkv to webm:

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i <input> -c:v libvpx -b:v 1500K -vf scale=-1:360 -an -map 0:v:0 <output>
```

What is wrong? I'm going to post more info about the source in 30 minutes, if you need it.

Comment: Show the console output of the command,

Comment: here is the relevant part https://pastebin.com/if9eNSkV

Comment: Basic filter would be `colormatrix=bt709:bt601` This goes before the scale. But without knowing all source properties and intended target, this is a crude guess.